# WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_* wrong

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 7 with Windows SDK 7.1, 8.0, and 8.1 installed.  For some reason, `$(WindowsSDK_Library_Path_x64)` is set to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\winv6.3\um\x64`

instead of

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64`.

Similarly with `_arm` and `_x86`.  This causes all sorts of problems beginning with "cannot open file kernel32.lib". How do I fix this without renaming the directory itself?  I had just installed SDK 8.0 so it can't be because it was corrupted by another program.  Thanks.

I searched my SDK directory and I found the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\SDKManifest.xml` which contains

```
<FileList
  DisplayName = "Windows 8.1"
  PlatformIdentity = "Windows, Version=8.1"      
  TargetFramework = ".NETCore,version=v4.5.1;.NETFramework,version=v4.5.1"
  MinVSVersion = "12.0"
  MinOSVersion = "6.3.0"
  MaxOSVersionTested = "6.3.0"
  UnsupportedDowntarget = "Windows, version=8.0">

  <File Reference = "Windows">
    <ToolboxItems VSCategory = "Toolbox.Default"/>
  </File>
</FileList>
```

Could the **winv6.3** come from this?

Comment: winv6.3 is Windows 8.1.  I'd guess you got it corrupted by installing SDK 8.0 *after* 8.1.  Reinstalling 8.1 would perhaps fix it.

Comment: @HansPassant I reinstalled 8.1, rebooted twice, but WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_* all disappeared and only WindowsSDKDir is left except its value is blank. Why is Microsoft development environment so seemingly complicated and opaque?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  I eventually found the incorrect path in this file:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.props"

After changing winv6.3 to win8 in the errant paths and restarting the IDE all was well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar build error in VS 2015, on a VS2012 c++ project

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Solution was to changing:
$(WindowsSdkDir)lib\winv6.3\um\x64;
to
$(WindowsSdkDir)lib\win8\um\x64;

in the Windows.props file.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.props"